# Implementing schemas in android app

Tags: android, schema

I am implementing a fragment in my application following the iosched open source application. I want to make use of one of its views but i found the following schema in one of the layouts i want to clone:

```
<view
    class="com.google.android.apps.iosched.ui.widget.ObservableScrollView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:iosched="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.google.android.apps.iosched">
```

This line in particular:

```
xmlns:iosched="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.google.android.apps.iosched"
```

What is that schemas thing about and how can i apply it in my application?

Answer (score 1):

> What is that schemas thing

It's an XML namespace prefix declaration. It only applies when the XML document is parsed.

In particular, it means that `iosched` is a prefix alias for

```
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.google.android.apps.iosched
```

When

```
iosched:foo
```

is encountered in the document being parsed, it is seen as

```
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.google.android.apps.iosched#foo
```

> how can i apply it in my application?

You can use it in the XML file it is declared in.

Comment: Do you know of a good document on how to apply this in our apps? i tried in google but i didn't find anything useful at all.